# scrapy, empty items that cause blank space in csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am close to finish a crawler with scrapy. The crawler is supposed to collect and extract data from page1 including links then it yields new requests (for all links collected on page1) to page2, collects again and extracts all required data and yields requests (all links again) to page3, collects data from page3 and ends. I have 3 output files and there are millions of such pages (page1,page2,page3). Now everything worked when I used return statements in my methods for single url's. Everything was coded properly and it worked well before I started to yield requests. I know were the error persists, but I am not sure when it happens and why? This is the error:

```
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:
```

And it happens because I yield a request without an URL, whole list is empty:

```
  2014-03-31 18:32:47+0200 [ah-h] WARNING: Dropped:
    {'gif_url': '',
     'link_referal': '',
     'model_id': '',
     'parts_name': '',
     'parts_number': ''}
```

So my code works fine as long as I don't yield a new Request(), here is my code:

```
def parse_part_list(self,response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    s = hxs.select('//tr')
    items = []
    for part in s:
        item = PartsItem()
        item['link_referal'] = "".join(part.select('td[@class="sel_sec_sub_section_even_col_2"]/a/@href | td[@class="sel_sec_sub_section_odd_col_2"]/a/@href').extract())            
        item['model_id'] = "".join(part.select('td[@class="sel_sec_sub_section_even_col_2"]/a/@href | td[@class="sel_sec_sub_section_odd_col_2"]/a/@href').extract())
        item['parts_number'] = "".join(part.select('td[@class="sel_sec_sub_section_even_col_2"]/a/@href | td[@class="sel_sec_sub_section_odd_col_2"]/a/@href').extract())
        item['parts_name'] = "".join(part.select('td[@class="sel_sec_sub_section_even_col_2"]/a/text() | td[@class="sel_sec_sub_section_odd_col_2"]/a/text()').extract())
        item['gif_url'] = "".join(part.select('td/@onmouseover').extract())
        yield item
        yield Request(item['link_referal'], callback=self.parse_frames)
        #items.append(item)
    #return items
```

Now if I comment out:

```
#yield Request(item['link_referal'], callback=self.parse_frames)
```

Everything will work fine and data will be scraped and extracted to my csv file, blank lines removed of course.

Empty Items are filtered out in pipelines.py, this is part of the code were it happens:

```
if isinstance(item, items.PartsItem):
        #check if expanded data is blank line
        if not(all(item.values())):
            raise DropItem()
        else:
            item['model_id'] = "".join(get_par_from_url(item['model_id'],'a'))
            item['parts_number'] = "".join(get_par_from_url(item['parts_number'],'b'))
            self.partsCsv.writerow([item['link_referal'],item['model_id'],item['parts_number'],item['parts_name'],item['gif_url']])
            return item
```

As you can see from code I am using DropItem() to remove empty items (blank rows in my csv file) 
But for some strange reason this part of code removes all items that are send to my pipeline once I yield a new request?
Any advice?

Comment: Why don't check for the `item['link_referal']` before yielding a `Request`: `if item['link_referal']: yield Request(...)`?

Comment: Why would I do that? The list is empty all the time...during FOR loop.